# WebSphere Liberty profile and Intellij: JMX administration should be enable

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere, jmx, websphere-liberty

Is anyone running the WebSphere 8.5.0.1 Liberty Profile from inside Intellij 12?

I have added a WebSphere Server Run Configuration, but all I get is:

> ```
> Error running WebSphere 8.5.0.1: JMX administration should be enabled
> ```

I can understand the error, but am not sure how to solve this within Intellij.  I added server.xml inside WebSphere to say:

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

But I am not sure Intellij is even reading this config file.

[image]

If anyone has this working, please tell me how.  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To make it possible for IDEA to administrate WebSphere LP with JMX, you should specify in the `server.xml`:

```
<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />
```

**in addition** to the fragment you've already specified:

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>
```

Actually, IDEA is able to make both changes for you -- you should just press the <kbd>Fix</kbd> button next to the `JMX administration should be enabled` message in the run configuration.

Comment: thanks for the update - i did that but still the same message.  I also don't see the "Fix" button (screenshot added to question).  Maybe my problem is more fundamental ?

Comment: Why don't you have a **Server** selected in the combo box?

Comment: thanks - I thought it would pick up defaultServer.  I created a new one using "bin/server create planetjones" and now Intellij is able to use that instance/profile.

Comment: I just wanted to add - if you F up the server.xml syntax, you won't get any fix button, but it seems tihs is the first thing IDEA complains about when the server.xml isn't as expected.

Comment: @StianStorrvik should get the credit. I had same exact problem and it looks like server.xml is corrupted. Once i fix server.xml file server came back normal. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see the "fix" button or you don't see the server you created in the drop down menu, it is likely a permissions issue.

If you are on your local box and don't really care about giving access to that folder:

```
chmod -R a+wrx /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/
```

Comment: and if you see "JMX administration should be enabled", have correct pertmissions and still no 'fix' button then chances are that you, like me, have typo somewhere (or in some other way invalid xml)